# std::istream does not throw eof exception (that has been enabled)

Tags: c++, stl, llvm, istream

I'm trying to parse a file using `std::istream` and want to use exceptions to simplify error handling. But the stream never throws exceptions on *eof* even though they are enabled.

Consider the following snippet:

```
std::string line("Lorem ipsum");
std::istringstream is(line);
is.exceptions(std::ios::eofbit | std::ios::failbit);

std::string value1, value2, value3;
is >> value1;
std::cout << is.eof() << std::endl;
is >> value2;
std::cout << is.eof() << std::endl;
is >> value3;
std::cout << is.eof() << std::endl;
```

After reading *value2*, `eof()` returns *true* but no exception gets thrown at any time even though the stream is instructed to do so (see line 3). At the end, *value3* contains an empty string.

What am I missing?

In case it matters: I'm using the LLVM libc++ that is part of Xcode 4.6.1 (LLVM C++ with C++11 support).

Comment: Works for me using g++ on Linux

Comment: @parkydr: Just out of curiosity: What's the output of the program using g++? Is *value2* still read without throwing an exception?

Comment: 0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
  what():  basic_ios::clear
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just reviewed both the libc++ implementation and the parts of the standard which specifies this behavior:

27.7.2.1 Class template basic_istream [istream]/p3:

> If `rdbuf()->sbumpc()` or `rdbuf()->sgetc()` returns `traits::eof()`, then
>   the input function, except as explicitly noted otherwise, completes
>   its actions and does `setstate(eofbit)`, which may throw
>   `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4), before returning.

And then p4:

> If one of these called functions throws an exception, then unless
>   explicitly noted otherwise, the input function sets `badbit` in error
>   state. If `badbit` is on in `exceptions()`, the input function rethrows
>   the exception without completing its actions, otherwise it does not
>   throw anything and proceeds as if the called function had returned a
>   failure indication.

I believe the crux here is the interpretation of "one of these called functions."  I interpreted that phrase to refer to all of the functions mentioned in the preceding paragraph, including `setstate(eofbit)`.  Under that interpretation, libc++'s behavior is correct since `badbit` is not set.

To get the behavior you desire, do:

```
is.exceptions(std::ios::eofbit | std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
```

Comment: Sounds to me that the key word in 27.7.2.1 is "may".

Comment: @Howard: I've observed the described behavior and it seems that the specification can be interpreted this way. But it makes little sense that requesting an exception on `std::ios::eofbit` has no effect other than setting `std::ios::badbit` instead of really throwing anything (from the perspective of the user).

Comment: This:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#submit_issue  is always an option for you if you disagree with how the standard is specified.